# What is the difference between using Wildcard or not?

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning about Wildcards and I dont think I understand the difference between `List<Number>` and `List<? extends Number>`. They say that the first is a list of Numbers only, and second is a list of Numbers or any of its subclasses. But every object of any subclass **is** instance of its superclass. Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

but you can do:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

When would it be useful? As a parameter type of methods accepting a heterogenous list of objects in same hierarchy, which only reads from such list. That's because, you can't write anything, but `null` to second kind of list reference, i.e., given the 2nd declaration, you can't do: `list.add(5);`